# COUNTIFS to count weeks before/after today in a plan?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple plan for projects. I'd like a spreadsheet to count the weeks done (before today), and those remaining (after today). It would look something like this:

[image]

I've been playing around with countifs, but I can't get it to work. I've done in cell B9: `=COUNTIFS(B4:E6,A9,B3:E3,"<="&C1)`. I'm getting #VALUE in cell B9.

I would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easily overlooked “gotchas” of the conditional IFS() functions is that all of the ranges must have the same dimensions.  Hence you are not going to be able to use COUNTIFS() for your particular situation.  You are going to have to resort to a slightly more complicated SUMPRODUCT() to get the result you want:

`SUMPRODUCT( ($B$4:$E$6=$A9) * (B$3<=$C$1) )`

The good news is that once you become comfortable with using binary operations on arrays of true/false conditions, you will find many, many powerful applications for the technique in Excel.

Please also note my use of the $ to deliberately lock the column for the A9 variable and the rows for the B3.  Also, if you want to be able to paste/fill the formulas through the range, you’ll notice I locked B4:E6 and C1.

Comment: Thanks! SUMPRODUCT looks like it could work, but that formula counts all of the instances for Project 1, Project 2 and Project 3 in the table, regardless of whether they are done or yet to be done. I've been playing around with the second argument, but I can't get it to look at row 3 to discriminate between weeks done and weeks remaining.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Here's the formula that worked for me: ```=SUMPRODUCT( ($B$4:$E$6=$A9) * ($B$3:$E$3<=$C$1) )```. Thanks a lot for your help!